# Publishing Failed in RAD 7 for WebSphere Portal Server 6

Tags: publish, websphere-portal, ibm-rad

I'm trying to publish my portal application to WPS 6. I get the message "Could not publish to the server". Moreover the Details button is disabled.
I checked IBM\WebSphere\PortalServer\log folder, I could not find any related logs for this error. Please suggest ways / ideas / workarounds  to proceed / resolve this issue.
RAD : 7.0.0.4
WebSphere Portal: 6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the steps i used to identify the issue.
 1. I enabled Error Log View in Eclipse. (Windows -> Show View -> Error Log).
 2. The Error log details gives sufficient information and stack trace to identify the issue.

```
     In this particular case, I found the exception to be
```

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.etools.portal.server.tools.v6.internal.WPServerBehaviour.getSourceFiles(Unknown Source)` 
Problem occurs if the project contains a file without any extension. 
Solution: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK55843